# Sampling image collection time series with large number of spatially dense points via indexing

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to use Google Earth Engine to extract a time series of SMAP L4 data at specified points. The problem is, I want to do this for over 300,00 points. Many of the points are spatially clustered, so there are places where a single SMAP pixel encompasses 10s to 100s of points I want to sample. Rather than sampling the same pixel over and over for each point (using reduceRegions), I want to extract the SMAP time series for a given pixel only once, and reference that time series via an indexing system for each of the points that fall within that pixel.

Are there any Google Earth Engine algorithms that can identify the index (e.g., row/column, lat/lon of the pixel center, etc) of pixels within which my sampling points are located?
I have browsed the GEE algorithms, and the closest thing I could find was ee.Image.PixelCoordinates, which didn't seem quite right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Although not the exact answer, this algorithm might help. It takes a feature collection of points and filters them so that no two points fall within some distance of each other.

```
var filterDistance = function(points, distance) {
  var filt2 = ee.List([])
  var filt = points.iterate(function(el, ini){
                         var ini = ee.List(ini)
                         var fcini = ee.FeatureCollection(ini)
                         var buf = ee.Feature(el).geometry().buffer(distance)
                         var s = fcini.filterBounds(buf).size()
                         var cond = s.lte(0)
                         return ee.Algorithms.If(cond, ini.add(el), ini)
                       }, filt2)
  var filtered = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(filt))
  return filtered
}
```

Its use is as follows:

```
// Input your points here
var myPoints = ee.FeatureCollection()

// Filter so that no points fall within 500 meters of another
var thinnedPoints = filterDistance(myPoints, 500)
```

I suspect you can adapt this algorithm to the spatial resolution of SMAP, which would get you close to the desired output.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, thank you Sean!